# Compile-time information in CUDA

Tags: optimization, cuda

I'm optimizing a very time-critical CUDA kernel.  My application accepts a wide range of switches that affect the behavior (for instance, whether to use 3rd or 5th order derivative).  Consider as an approximation a set of 50 switches, where every switch is an integer variable (a bool sometimes, or a float, but this case is not so relevant for this question).

All these switches are constant during the execution of the application.  Most of these switches are run-time and I store them in constant memory, so to exploit the caching mechanism.  Some other switches can be compile-time and the customer is fine with having to re-compile the application if he wants to change the value in the switch.  A very simple example could be:

```
__global__ void mykernel(const float* in, float *out)
{
    for ( /* many many times */ )
        if (compile_time_switch)
            do_this(in, out);
        else
            do_that(in, out);
}
```

Assume that `do_this` and `do_that` are compute-bound and very cheap, that I optimize the `for` loop so that its overhead is negligible, that I have to place the `if` inside the iteration.  If the compiler recognizes that `compile_time_switch` is static information it can optimize out the call to the "wrong" function and create code that is just as optimized as if the if weren't there.  Now the real question:

In which ways can I provide the compiler with the static value of this switch?  I see two such ways, listed below, but none of them work for me.  What other possibilities remain?

---

### Template parameters

Providing a template parameter enables this static optimization.

```
template<int compile_time_switch>
__global__ void mykernel(const float* in, float *out)
{
    for ( /* many many times */ )
        if (compile_time_switch)
            do_this(in, out);
        else
            do_that(in, out);
}
```

This simple solution does not work for me, since I don't have direct access to the code that calls the kernel.

### Static members

Consider the following struct:

```
struct GlobalParameters
{
    static const bool compile_time_switch = true;
};
```

Now `GlobalParameters::compile_time_switch` contains the static information as I want it, and that compiler would be able to optimize the kernel.  Unfortunately, CUDA does not support such static members.

EDIT: the last statement is apparently wrong.  the definition of the struct is of course legit and you are able to use the static member `GlobalParameters::compile_time_switch` in device code. The compiler inlines the variable, so that the final code will directly contain the value, not a run-time variable access, which is the behavior you would expect from an optimizer compiler. So, the second options is actually suitable.

I consider my problem solved both thanks to this fact and to kronos' answer. However, I'm still looking for other alternative methods to provide compile-time information to the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Yor third options are preprocessor definitions:

```
#define compile_time_switch 1

__global__ void mykernel(const float* in, float *out)
{
    for ( /* many many times */ )
        if (compile_time_switch)
            do_this(in, out);
        else
            do_that(in, out);
}
```

The preprocessor will discard the else case compleatly and the compiler has nothing to optimize in his dead code elemination pass, because there is no dead code.

Furthermore, you can specify the definition with the -D comand line switch and (I think) any by nvidia supported compiler will accept -D (msvc may use a different switch).

Comment: Ok, yes, thanks for sharing. This is our current solution, actually. We try to move away from exploiting too much the preprocessor since it makes the code less readable and besides, we would like to have similar mechanism for both compile-time and run-time switches, i.e., whether the switch is compile-time or run-time should be as transparent as possible from the user's point of view (user = the programmer that reads the switch).

Comment: @Spiros Yves Daoust has made some edits to my post. The changes increase the readability of the code.

Comment: Oh, yes, of course you can use macros this way. So, to summarize, using the preprocessor is a valid alternative. I'm still looking for other possible ways of specifying compile-time information so that the compiler can optimize out dead code.